# Unable to resize my main partition (CentOS 6.4 x86_x64) Google Cloud Compute

Tags: partition

> Disk /dev/sda: **268.4 GB**, 268435456000 bytes
>   4 heads, 32 sectors/track, 4096000 cylinders
>   Units = cylinders of 128 * 512 = 65536 bytes
>   Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
>   I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
>   Disk identifier: 0x0003ba74
>     Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
>   /dev/sda1              17      163825    10483712+  83  Linux
>   /dev/sda2          163841     2621440   157286400   83  Linux

root@webserver04 [/tmp]# resize2fs /dev/sda1

> resize2fs 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
>   The filesystem is already 2620928 blocks long.  Nothing to do!

root@webserver04 [/]# df -h

> Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
>   /dev/**sda1**       **9.8G**  8.6G  647M  94% /
>   /dev/**sda2**       **148G**   34G  107G  24% /home
>   /dev/sdb2       483G   12G  446G   3% /backup

**NOTE : Theres no rescue mode as i know on Google Cloud Compute.**

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it in this way -
first you need to resize the partition-
* you must umount the partition first.
for example(1 is the number of the partition):
parted /dev/sda resizepart 1 200G
then 
use resize2fs /dev/sda1

Comment: Can i umount the main partition without goes in rescue mode? cause on google theres no rescue mode..

Comment: check this out -https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-root-persistent-disks#manualrepartition